# Graphics processing in general

Tags: .net, graphics

I am quite familiar with the .Net framework and graphics processing is quite essential for my implementations. It is easy to import a bitmap and manipulate it like negating it or changing contrast etc. It can be done pixel by pixel, which is how I do it but it really takes a long time on higher resolution images. And then there is matrix methods, where you enter translation and rotation data into the matrix, apply the transformation and somehow the image is magically processed instantly.

I want to know how I can write my own matrix methods, I don't want to use built-in functions. I am familiar with the workings of matrix mechanics( as an engineering student I had 8 math subjects in two years ) and I have an idea of how it's applied to graphics processing; but I still can't see how an image is processed so quickly by graphics software such as Photoshop and even MS-Paint, it can surely not be pixel by pixel operations.

Can anyone advise me on the basic methodology in achieving such efficiency in processing images?

Regards
Charl

Comment: Graphics software image processing algorithms do their calculations, (matrix transformations and such) on the graphical unit of the processor (as is build into modern processors).

Comment: You could study the source of free software doing things like those interesting you. Perhaps Gtk http://gtk.org/ (and Gimp) should interest you, but I don't understand your question... Some software use the GPU, read more about OpenCL & OpenGL...

Comment: Yes, they do operate pixel-by-pixel, sometimes on the CPU, sometimes on the GPU. You can improve the speed (particularly of matrix math) by use SIMD instructions to calculate more than one value at a time, and you can use multi-processing (see OpenMP for example) to do the calculations on more than one core at a time.

Comment: You want to see how it is done, check Paint.NET which is an open-source project and a great tool and the whole app is created using .NET API.